# PHP, convert UTF-8 to ASCII 8-bit

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, ascii, iconv

I'm trying to convert a string from UTF-8 to ASCII 8-bit by using the `iconv` function. The string is meant to be imported into an accounting software (some basic instructions parsed accordingly to SIE standards).

What I'm running now:

```
iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII", $this->_output)
```

This works for accounting software #1, but software #2 complains about the encoding. Specified encoding by the standard is: `IBM PC 8-bit extended ASCII (Codepage 437)`.

My question is, what version of ASCII is PHP encoding my string into, and if other than specified - how can I encode the string accordingly to the standard specification?

Comment: What kind of characters are in the string? If only characters of the first 128 code points, then UTF-8 is already identical to ASCII. Is there are other characters in there, then you're discarding a lot of information/characters.

Comment: It's a matter of compatibility. The importing software will follow the SIE standard and therefor only accept ASCII extended.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this for the software #2

```
iconv("UTF-8", "CP437", $this->_output);
```

Extended ASCII is not the same as plain ASCII.
The first one maybe accepts ASCII, but the second software requires Extended ASCII - Codepage 437

see this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)

Comment: Thank you, software #2 does no longer warn about the encoding.